# Using one of DBML schemes depending on parameter

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have an application which should support two versions of databases based on configuration parameter.
The problem is that there is some slight differences between the types in tables of those databases.
For example on old database, the field is of type `tinyint` and now it's `smallint`.

When I try to use the new `.dbml` file I get a cute `InvalidCastException` when trying to select anything.

I need two different .dbml schemes with same tables and column names but different types.
I'd like to avoid duplicating the code like:

```
if (newDatabaseVersionFlag)
{
    Data.DatabaseDataContext context = new Data.DatabaseDataContext(connectionString);
    Data.Something item = context.Somethings.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
    item.Sth = (short)5;
    item.Sth2 = "sample code";
}
else
{
    Data2.DatabaseDataContext context2 = new Data2.DatabaseDataContext(connectionString);
    Data2.Something item2 = context2.Somethings.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
    item2.Sth = (byte)5;
    item2.Sth2 = "sample code";
}
```

And there's a lot more of code than that...

What is the best way to make it neat and clean?

Answer (score 0):

You will be best to create a Proxy Data Context.

The issue is if you have different data types, your compiler will fail unless you are using the var

```
public class UseMeDataContext:System.Data.Linq.DataContext

{
...
}


UseMeDataContext db ;
if (newDatabaseVersionFlag)
{
    db = ((System.Data.Linq.DataContext) new Data.DatabaseContext(connectionString));
}
else
{
    db  = ((System.Data.Linq.DataContext) new Data2.DatabaseDataContext(connectionString));

}

db.Something item2 = UseMeContext.Somethings.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
    item2.Sth =  (TypeOf(item2.sth))5; // May or May not Need typing
    item2.Sth2 = "sample code";
```

Comment: I tried to do something similar but the `Data.DatabaseContext.Something` is a different class from `Data2.DatabaseContext.Something` so I can't assign them to a common variable. I'm using .NET 3.5 so there's no `dynamic` keyword here

Comment: Are the classes of different types?  do they have a common parent type

Comment: They are generated automatically by `MSLinqToSQLGenerator` tool

Comment: If have just edited my code to reflect System.Data.Linq.DataContext .  This should work because the object have the same base datatype

Comment: It won't because `System.Data.Linq.DataContext` doesn't have `Somethings` in it

Comment: The only other way I can think of is have another layer in your application that is your application objects, and map from your DBML to this data access layer. Your application objects would have to map to the lowest common datatype - e.g. byte.